# Elixir's Range for arithmetic progression

Tags: haskell, elixir

Is it possible to express arithmetic progression in a list without listing them all?

In Haskell, you could do it with the range function.

```
[2,4..10] == [2,4,6,8,10]
```

Is there a similar way to do it with Elixir ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Stream.iterate/2](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Stream.html#iterate/2) does what you want:

```
Stream.iterate(2, &(&1+2))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use Erlang's [`lists:seq`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#seq-3) function, from Elixir:

```
:lists.seq(2,10,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, there is a Stream.seq() added a month ago:

- [Add Stream.seq() for generating potentially infinite streams of values](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/pull/1388)
- [Add a range/step/seq function](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/1039)